# PHP add thousand separators to number and keep leading zeros

Tags: php, numbers, number-formatting

I'm trying to add thousand separators to a number using PHP and at the same time keep the leading zeros (It's part of the design of an app that the leading 0s stay so that people can see the number grow towards the set target - a 6 figure number).

My initial attempt was to use str_pad to add the leading zeros if the current number calculated was less than 6 figures long. Then to add the commas I used number_format. The obvious issue is that number_format removes the leading 0s.

```
$num = 550;
$num_padded = str_pad($num, 6, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
echo number_format($num_padded);
```

So that returns 550 instead of 000,550

Does anyone know of a reliable way to achieve the format I'm looking for?

Thanks!

Comment: use first `number_format` and then `str_pad`?

Comment: Do you really need `number_format` ?

Comment: `str_pad` input must be a string, not an integer.

Comment: I don't need number format but I need that comma! :)

Comment: @manolo - PHP will cast str_pad() input to a string if it isn't one already

Comment: I'm probably complicating this. If I know the length of the number will always be six digits I know the position of the comma will always be the same.

Comment: @MarkBaker - All right. I didn't know. My belief was based on http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have in mind this simple trick:

```
function padAndFormat($number, $length)
{
   if(strlen($number)>=$length)
   {
      return number_format($number);
   }
   $number = number_format('1'.str_pad($number, $length-1, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT));
   $number[0] = '0';
   return $number;
}

//var_dump(padAndFormat('517', 6)); //string(7) "000,517"
```

Comment: That's close. It works as expected up to entering a 6 figure number but if a 6 figure number is used it add an another comma and zero to the start of the number.

Comment: My though was that length will always be less than your number. Easily fixed now :p

Answer (score 2):

another way to do this is to use sprintf

```php
// length can be changed, here is 6
implode(',',str_split(sprintf('%06d', $this->iterator),3));
```

the result will be :

| input | result |
| --- | --- |
| 4 | 000,004 |
| 400 | 000,400 |
| 23560 | 023,560 |
| 1234567 | 1,234,567 |

it can be improved by reading the length, and computing automatically the final length, multiple of 3

Comment: Yes Raphael!  Excellent first contribution!  You found an old, open question and delivered a unique, valuable, clean, brief, professional-looking, considered, proven answer.  Please continue adding value to Stack Overflow in this way.  (and if you can, teach a thousand other PHP developers to behave the same way)

Answer (score 0):

> I don't need number format but I need that comma! :)

```
<?php
$zeroes=0;
$num = 550;
$num_padded = str_pad($zeroes, 3, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
$num_padded = str_pad($num_padded,strlen($num_padded)+strlen($zeroes), ',', STR_PAD_RIGHT);
$num_padded = str_pad($num_padded,strlen($num_padded)+strlen($num), $num, STR_PAD_RIGHT);
echo $num_padded;
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
000,550
```

Answer (score 0):

One Liner with PHP string manipulation. Works for any number of digits:

```
function pad($number, $min_digits){
    return strrev(implode(",",str_split(str_pad(strrev($number), $min_digits, "0", STR_PAD_RIGHT),3)));
}

/* Output for 9 digits
0,000,001
0,000,012
0,000,123
0,001,234
0,012,345
0,123,456
1,234,567
12,345,678
123,456,789
/**/
```

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.  While it is nice that you express a list of reformatted strings, it would be better to understand how your technique works and why you recommend it in a professional script.